# Предложение изменить фразу "Голосование исправлено" при серийном голосовании

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Заметил у одного [пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20184/dark-byte?tab=reputation) откат голосов за серийное голосование:

> [image: репутация]
>
> [image: хинт]

Я думаю фраза "Голосование исправлено" звучит не совсем корректно и информативно (да, я вижу ссылку на *подробнее*), потому что "исправлено" подразумевает, что был баг, однако это не так.

Предлагаю изменить причину на более соответствующую.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю изменить фразу на "Серийное голосование".

Было:

> -35   03:00   отмена  Голосование исправлено (подробнее)

станет:

> -35   03:00   отмена  Серийное голосование (подробнее)

Comment: Такой вариант наверное не очень подходит, т.к. нет уверенности, что именно серийное голосование стало причиной коррекции. Может быть дело в чем-то еще.

Comment: @alexolut в основном, в информации говорится о серийном голосовании, поэтому такое предложение. *Может быть дело в чем-то еще* - вряд ли, т.к. это касается именно накрутки (voting up) или очевидной мести(voting down), во всяком случае другие примеры мне неизвестны.

Comment: Возможно Вы правы, т.к. даже ссылка [(подробнее)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) имеет в адресе фразу `serial-voting-reversed`. Но надо убедиться, что не появляется аналогичная запись при коррекции голосов модератором (если такое возможно), иначе это будет вводить в заблуждение.

Comment: @alexolut Модератор не может влиять на голоса. Вручную откорректировать голоса могут буквально несколько человек в компании. Корректировка может произойти исключительно в случаях, когда на лицо явное нарушение правил голосования, но система по каким–то причинам не отменила голоса автоматически.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky нарушение правил всё равно можно назвать как "серийное голосование"? Или в этом случае будет какая-то кастомная причина? Всё не могу понять, может ли текущий ответ покрывать все случаи.

Comment: @alexolut Нарушение, по сути, в случае голосов, бывает только одно – серийное голосование. Голосование – дело субъективное, так что нарушать больше нечего.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тогда текущий ответ мне кажется более предпочтительным. Кстати, надо бы разрешить на Мете менять голоса без необходимости редактирования вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Изменения излишни, менять не нужно.

Comment: В [оригинале](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/44043286?key=e5f8bf1ffbcd82397be0bc56128c0a06) это `Voting corrected`, т.о. перевод вполне подходящий.

Comment: @alexolut если следовать дословному переводу, то да. Но как-то режет слово __исправлено__. Сразу возникает вопрос - _а что сломалось?_

Comment: всё-таки *исправлено* и *починено* это не одно и то же, чтобы говорить о сломанности. Но может быть можно изменить на *подправлено*. Или еще более дословно *откорректировано*.

Answer (score -1):

**Голосование аннулировано**

В духе всей серьезности российской части SO, и лучших совковых традиций.

Comment: Или еще вариант: "а было ли голосование?"

Comment: Как мне кажется, самый подходящий вариант!

Comment: Может «голоса аннулированы»?

Comment: единственный минус - участник не увидит сразу причину аннулирования.

Comment: @Alex для этого есть ссылка "подробнее". Любая короткая фраза здесь не будет достаточно понятна для видящего это в первый раз, т.к. если бы она была понятна, не было бы необходимости в подробной справке.

Comment: @alexolut я не имею ввиду нового участника, таким участникам очень много непонятно, и да, для них есть ссылка. Я не против данного варианта, а только указал на минусы. Самый простой пример: представьте, что вы делаете скриншот репутации и там фразы типа "голосование исправлено", "голосование аннулировано", "голосование откорректировано", "серийное голосование" и прочее. Что меньше всего у Вас вызовет вопросов ?

Answer (score -2):

Если "исправлено" ассоциируется со сломанностью, то предлагаю следующий вариант:

> Голосование откорректировано